# Rotation Atan2 CCW CW continuity

Tags: c++, ios, math

**This is what I have**

- I have a plane in 2D X,Y
- I set his destination by clicking on the screen X', Y'
- I calculate the angle it needs to turn to face this destination with:

```
// Calculate the angle between plane position and destination point

CVector3 facingVec = m_vDestination - m_vPosition;
fAngle = -Math::radiansToDegrees (  (float)atan2f(m_vDestination.x - m_vPosition.x, m_vDestination.y - m_vPosition.y)  )  ;

//This doesn't work, when rotating from ex. 350 degree to 0 
//plane has to go all the way around 360,350,340,330,
//...,120,...100,90,..down to zero
float angleToTurn = fAngle - m_fRotationAngle;
if(angleToTurn < 0)
{
    angleToTurn += 360.0f;
}

m_fRotationAngle += (angleToTurn) / 5;

// Move the unit towards the calculated angle m_fRotationAngle

m_vDirection.x =   (-sin(Math::degreesToRadians(m_fRotationAngle)));
m_vDirection.y =   (cos(Math::degreesToRadians(m_fRotationAngle)));

m_vPosition += ( 2 * m_vDirection * fDelta);
```

**This is how it looks like**

> [YT Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvKFuySFW3Q) - sorry for the demo version, i couldn't get anything free at this moment.

**This is what I need**

- I need this to behave properly, let's say plane is rotated at angle 350.
  I set the destination and new angle should be 15.

Instead of going: 350,340,330,320,310,300,290,...10,0,15
It should continue: 350,0,15

Hope you can help me out with this guys, I've already dropped bezier approach - and I'm struggling with this since few days now.

Comment: when trying to watch the video you tube says "this video is private". Please make it public.

Comment: is it possible that the coordinate system is rotated in the video? It seems to me the problem appears when the cursor is below the plane. You should handle the case when m_vDestination.y - m_vPosition.y == 0 separately as then the atan2f will have problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this correctly, you're trying to find the smallest angle to interpolate between the two vectors? If so, the following algorithm should work:

1. Find the angle of the first vector, relative to the fixed vector [1, 0]. This is a1.
2. Find the angle of the second vector, relative to the fixed vector [1, 0]. This is a2.
3. Let da = a2 - a1.
4. if da > 180, da -= 360;
5. else if da < 180, da += 360;

You need to calculate the angles with respect to another third vector [1, 0] so you can determine weather to rotate left or right.

**Edit:** I saw your YouTube link was broken, now I see it's working again. I think my answer is what you're after.

Comment: I already solved the issue meantime, with a similar approach. Thanks Liam - good job !

Comment: No worries! It's a simple problem, but I think we all deal with this at one stage or another :).

Comment: Gee, sometimes i feel like i should sue my math teacher ;-)
Lovely stuff i have this done mate, i can now continue with this stuff :)  have a great weekend Liam :)

Comment: @PeeS Haha, me too. Thanks, you too mate.